# Check Chrome's certificate keystore javascript, e.g. to determine if a user has already downloaded and installed a certificate

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a user has already been into my site and downloaded the custom certificate (self-signed). I understand that javascript can't do that, but was thinking maybe a way it can check for Chrome? Since Chrome maintains a keystore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the only way I was able to figure it out so far is by checking that the URL has https and then subsequently checking the content of the page (e.g. if certificate is untrusted the content would mention something ...)  for the absence of errors related to certificate or t=for the existence of the normal content I would expect to be there... Doing that I was abel to overcome this and prompt users to download a package with the custom certificate and instructions etc... Please suggest if anyone has come across a better option.